# Pass/convert a php comma separated string to a js array due localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I can't figure out how to pass/convert a php comma separated string to a javascript array due localstorage. I store:

```
...
$SelectedPlaces = "101,102,103";
...
<script>    
localStorage.setItem("SelectedPlaces", "<?php echo $SelectedPlaces; ?>");
</script>
```

I must retrieve later on in javascript array like:

```
var bookedSeats = [101,102,103];
```

but how to write the localStorage.getItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `String.split` function with `Number` constructor(to convert substrings into numbers) when getting a certain "string" item from localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("SelectedPlaces", "<?php echo $SelectedPlaces; ?>");

var places = localStorage.getItem("SelectedPlaces").split(",").map(Number);

console.log(places);    // [101, 102, 103]
```

Comment: Aaaah, that's the way, thanks! I was struggling with JSON.stringify and .parse with no luck and overlooked this way.